# ¿Por qué perro y gato tienen tanto género masculino como femenino?

Tags: género, animales

En español las palabras tienen genero masculino, femenino o neutro. Algunas tienen más de uno. Es el caso de *perro* y *perra*, *gato* y *gata*. Sin embargo, en Latin, la palabra usada es única (*canis* y *feles*). Me surge la duda de donde proviene su diferenciación. **¿Será por la cercanía de estos animales a los seres humanos?** De hecho, son muy pocos los animales que tienen ambos géneros (¿más ejemplos?). La mayoría tienen nombres únicos (jirafa, elefante, caballo, sapo, etc) o diferenciados (vaca/toro, oveja/carnero, etc).

Comment: Un contraejemplo: _león_ y _leona_.

Comment: "Caballo" no tiene un nombre único. La hembra del caballo es la yegua.

Comment: @wimi Si. Ver última parte de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Gato y gata son dos palabras.  Cada palabra tiene su género.  En este caso, el género linguístico corresponde al género biológico,  pero eso no es una regla general.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Algunos contraejemplos (con cambio o agregación de la a):

León - Leona

Zorro - Zorra

Cerdo - Cerda

Oso - Osa

Burro - Burra

Mono - Mona

**NOTA**: bien es cierto que muchos de ellos tienen connotaciones

Algunos ejemplos para los que cambia completamente el nombre:

Toro - Vaca

Caballo - Yegua

Tigre - Tigresa

Carnero - Oveja

Gallo - Gallina

Answer (score 0):

En la lengua española la mayoría de los nombres de animales son epicenos, es decir,
tienen un solo género gramatical, si por alguna razón los desconoces o te resultan raros, el diccionario será el que te indique cual es el género gramatical con el que habitualmente se deben nombrar, si masculino o femenino, ésto no indica el sexo biológico, pues una cosa es el género de la palabra y otra cosa es el sexo de la persona o del animal.

Normalmente este género gramatical se aplica a los sustantivos que denotan indistintamente animales o personas de sexo masculino o femenino, el sexo se distinguirá añadiendo algún especificador al sustantivo, en los animales serán especificadores las palabras "macho" o "hembra".

En lo referente a las personas, **los sustantivos epicenos** más habituales son; *persona, personaje, víctima, ayudante o genio*.

Por último, en obras teatrales, poéticas, cuentos para niños o usos humorísticos, es posible utilizar un género gramatical distinto para indicar un sexo biológico, así podría decirse " Y dijo el Sr. Jirafo a través de sus lentes.... o en un mar muy lejano vivían una vez una Ballena y un Balleno con sus tres hijos ballenatos... Y le dijo la Foca al Foco....